# If $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of positive terms and $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ then $\sum a_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know this is false but I came up with a proof where I can't find a mistake. The proof is

By the hypothesis $\forall \epsilon \gt 0$, $ \exists N \gt 0$ such that $n \ge N$ implies $a_n \lt \dfrac{\epsilon}{q-p+1}$ where $q \ge p \ge N$.
Hence we can say that

$\begin{align}
  a_p &\lt \dfrac{\epsilon}{q-p+1} \\
  a_{p+1} &\lt \dfrac{\epsilon}{q-p+1} \\
  \vdots \\
  a_q &\lt \dfrac{\epsilon}{q-p+1}
 \end{align}$

Adding all these we get $\displaystyle\sum_{p}^{q} a_n =\left| \displaystyle\sum_{p}^{q} a_n \right| \lt \epsilon$

$\therefore \sum a_n$ converges by Cauchy Criteria.
Can somebody spot the mistake in this?

**Edit:** I found my mistake. By hypothesis for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an integer $N > 0$, such that $a_n < \epsilon$, for all $n \ge N$, which does not implies $a_n \lt \dfrac{\epsilon}{q-p+1}$ for $q \ge p \ge N$. So my argument was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The larger you make $q$, the larger you have to make $N$ to make sure that $a_n$ is still small enough. That's not the way the definition of limit goes. You have to find a single $N$ that works for *any* $p, q\geq N$.

Answer (score 1):

If the  sequence $(a_n)_n$ is non-negative and $\exists N \gt 0$ such that **forall** $n \ge N$, $a_n \lt \dfrac{\epsilon}{q-p+1}$ **for all** $q \ge p \ge N$, it follows, by letting $q\to\infty$,  that $a_n=0$ eventually.  In this special case, the series $\sum_n a_n$ is convergent.